# How to pass a blank bytes calldata into a solidity function call?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function foo(uint _someVar, bytes calldata _data) public {
    ...
}
```

Then I make a call to it from another function with `""` as `_data`:

```
foo(123, "");
```

`""` seems to be the default way to pass blank bytes. However, I get this truffle compilation error:

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "" to bytes calldata requested.
```

I have tried to declare and pass variables, but it all comes down to trying to assign blank calldata bytes. Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Use `new bytes(0)`.

Comment: This does not work in Solidity `0.8.24`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use "0x". It helps me.

Comment: This worked. It's so stupid that an empty string won't.

Comment: This does not work in Solidity `0.8.24`.

Answer (score 2):

```
bytes memory data = new bytes(0);
```

Comment: While this seems to answer the question, please avoid code only answer.